# JavaScript Фильтр массива

Tags: javascript

есть 2 массива :

```
let massive1 = ["1","2","3"];
let massive2 = ["1","2"];
```

Нужно из массива 1 убрать элементы , которые есть в массиве 2.
Пробовал сделать так, но не помогло:

```
massive1.filter((array1) => massive2.find((array2) => array2 !== array1));
```

Comment: `massive1.filter((elOfarr1) => !massive2.find((elOfarr2) => elOfarr2 == elOfarr1));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let massive1 = ["1","2","3"];
let massive2 = ["1","2"];

let result = massive1.filter((elOfarr1) => !massive2.find((elOfarr2) => elOfarr2 == elOfarr1)); 
console.log(result);

//-------------
// Второй вариант 

result = massive1.filter(x => !massive2.includes(x));
console.log(result);

//-------------
// Третий вариант 

result = massive1.filter(i => massive2.indexOf(i) < 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло